# trouble in admin pages showing name in select for foreign key instead of id

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have two models Client and Master.  Master has a foreign key to client.  I am trying to get the select for the foreign key to display the name in the admin pages but getting an error.

Here is the client model

```
class Client(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True),
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    clientEmail = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    clientPhone = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
    clientCompany = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and here is an abbreviated Master

```
class Master(models.Model):
    id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key = True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user_metadata = models.JSONField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False, null = True)
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=False, null = True)

   #abbreviated

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_name

    def c_name(self):
        return self.client.name
```

and the admin.py

```
class MasterDataAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = ( 'id', 'c_name','user_name', 'account_status')

admin.site.register(Master, MasterDataAdmin)
```

Now when I go to the Master in admin pages I get...

```
OperationalError at /admin/kdconnector/master/
no such column: kdconnector_master.client_id
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/kdconnector/master/
Django Version: 4.1.7
Exception Type: OperationalError
Exception Value:    
no such column: kdconnector_master.client_id
Exception Location: C:\Users\MikeOliver\KDConnectorSite\venv\Lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py, line 357, in execute
Raised during:  django.contrib.admin.options.changelist_view
Python Executable:  C:\Users\MikeOliver\KDConnectorSite\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.11.3
```

I tried the following example that works.

```
class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def author_name(self):
        return self.author.name


admin.site.register(Author)
admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

Seems like I followed the same paradigm but no luck.

Comment: I had someone give me the author and book example that works, but it doesn't work on my client master relationship.  the error shows client_id but there is no explicit client_id in either model.  Should I drop the foreign key, and add it back and migrate again if that will help?

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Please delete & flag obsolete comments. Debug questions require a [mre]. [ask] [Help]

Comment: Have you run both `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands?

Answer (score 0):

Quite by accident, the problem was resolved when I commented out the

```
# def c_name(self):
#     return self.client.name
```

All it took was just the **str** in each model.  Now not only does the select show the name instead of id and the list shows the name instead of the id in the admin pages.